# Open GL Change Color over Time

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

So I have my programming working that has particles flowing from the top of the screen(snow) to the bottom and I want the color of the particles to change from white to silver over time, but my problem is that the particles start as green and change to light blue

[image]

The code that I'm using is in the fragment file

```
#version 430 core

in float ee_time;
out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    if (ee_time >0.8f) discard;
    fColor = vec4(0*(ee_time - int(ee_time)), 1 - ee_time - int(ee_time),  ee_time - int(ee_time), 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to interpolate between 2 colors, the I recommend to define the 2 colors:

e.g.

```
vec4 color1 = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
vec4 color2 = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

and to use the [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) function to linear interpolate between them:

```
float a = ee_time - int(ee_time);
fColor = mix(color1, color2, a);
```